# how to add chinese input on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: chinese

I've tried to add ***Chinese*** input on ***Ubuntu 16.04***,  but it **doesn't** work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information. What did you try? What was the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use **gcin**, it's easily installed.

```
sudo apt-get install gcin
im-config # this will show a windows, just select ok and then yes
```

After the `im-config` command, a window will pop out. Just select gcin, press ok, then login and logout. Now you should see a new icon on the upper right of your screen and be able to use Chinese input by pressing `<ctrl> + <space>`